# Why array.pop() doesn't work on my private network?

Tags: remix, gas-limit, poa

I have deployed a PoA network using Hyperledger Besu and I'm using Remix in order to code a very simple smart contract.

Here is the smart contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.8;

contract management {
    address [] public addressArray;                           // List of accounts agents
    constructor( ) public {
        addressArray.push (0x5170147D2e73C876Ab19dA687fBBC0fDD7d5C24B);
        addressArray.push (0x81537B2D16C0107E4E5368a96C34CddE631f6574);
        addressArray.push (0x3A1efCfF3C76BF5a4EF07264C7b13097f3111d8e);
        addressArray.push (0x4048cA94C733470FD968C849Df0BD61C4d472550);
        addressArray.push (0xa021Fbd79c01419F1867058597713D25fEb0cC91);
        addressArray.push (0x4637EC7fe8C8Eb7Dd6B5B087070B99b4c4b86137);
    }
    
    function removeAgent () public {
        
        addressArray.pop();
        
    }
    
    function addAgent (address _newAddress) public {
        addressArray.push(_newAddress);
    }
}
```

When I deploy the smart contract, I can access to array elements and I can use addAgent method, but if I try to send the transaction of removeAgent method, I get this error on Remix:

> transact to management.removeAgent errored: Error: Returned error: Intrinsic gas exceeds gas limit

I have tried to use a large number of gas (6000000000), but the error persists. If I comment the addressArray.pop() code line, I can use the method.

So, what's the problem with addressArray.pop()? Any idea?

Comment: Can you try changing "EVM version" to "byzantium" in the Remix's compiler setting? Perhaps solc uses an opcode that is not implemented in besu yet.

Comment: @Ismael thank you for your answer. I just tried all the EVM version with the same result.

Comment: Is the array empty? I'd check besu logs for some error. The solidity code seems correct. I'd say it is something with besu, perhaps you can try asking besu developers.

Comment: @Ismael no, the array is not empty since is filled in constructor method. 
An update: if I use addressArray.pop() on constructor (after the last push()), then pop works (array Length is 5 then). So, the problem is using array.pop() in a function...

Answer (score 1):

Finally, as @Ismael said, it seems to be a problem with Besu. I updated from version 1.4.4 to 1.5.0 and now it's working properly.